# Share editable dataframe between modules

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive

I'm trying to share data between modules using reactive values, using [this](https://www.ardata.fr/en/post/2019/04/22/share-reactive-among-shiny-modules/) idea, but shiny throws an error when it tries to pass on the updated data, `rv$data` is not a dataframe but a reactive object I think. In detail, the datatable is summarized in the summary table, and also plotted. When the datatable is edited, I'd like the summary table and plot to also update.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

#summary modules----
summary_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("summary_table"))
}

summary_server <- function(id,data){
    shiny::moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            output$summary_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
                sum_data <- data %>%
                    group_by(Brand) %>%
                    summarise_all(list(sum))
                
                DT::datatable(sum_data, editable = TRUE)
            })
        })
}

#data table modules----
data_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("data_table"))
}


data_server <- function(input, output, session, data,reset) {
    
    print(isolate(colnames(data)))
    output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data, editable = TRUE)
    })
}

#edit datatable----
edit_server <- function(input, output, session, data) {
    
    ns <- session$ns
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy("data_table")

    observeEvent(input$data_table_cell_edit, {
        print(names(data))
        info = input$data_table_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        k = info$value
        str(info)

        isolate(
            if (j %in% match(c("ratio","cost","updated_price"), names(data))) {
                print(match(c("ratio","cost", "updated_price"), names(data)))
                data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, data[i, j])
                print(data)

                if (j %in% match("cost", names(data))) {
                    data$updated_price <<- data$cost * data$ratio
                }
                if (j %in% match("ratio", names(data))) {
                    data$updated_price <<- data$cost * data$ratio
                }
            } else {
                stop("You are not supposed to change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
            }
        )
        replaceData(proxy, data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
    })

    result <- reactiveValues(
        data=NULL,
        trigger=NULL
    )

    result$data <- data
    result$trigger <- 1
    
    return(result)
}

#plot modules----
plot_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    plotOutput(ns(id))
}

plot_server <- function(id,data){
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input,output,session){
            
            output$price_plot <- renderPlot({
                ns <- NS(id)
                data %>%
                    ggplot()+
                    aes(x=cost,y=updated_price)+
                    geom_point()
            })
        })
}

#dataset-----------------------
input_data <- data.frame(Brand = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3","Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3","Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                         ratio = rep(0.5,9),
                         cost = seq(from=100,to=1000,length.out=9)) %>%
    mutate(updated_price = cost * ratio)

#ui----------------------------------------
ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(6,data_ui(id="data_table")),
        column(6,plot_ui(id="price_plot"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(6,summary_ui(id="summary_table"))
    ),
)

#server-----------------------------------------
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(data = input_data,trigger=NULL)
    observe({  rv$data <- input_data  })
    
    #data table----------------------
    callModule(data_server,"data_table", data=rv$data)
    
    #edit table----
    data_mod <- callModule(module = edit_server, id = "mod",data = reactive(rv$data))
    observeEvent(data_mod$trigger,{
        #error: rv reactiveValue not being updated correctly
        rv$data <- data_mod$data
        })
    
    #summary table----
    summary_server("summary_table",data=rv$data)
    
    #plot----
    plot_server(id="price_plot",data=rv$data)
}    

#app-----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In all your modules except where is function parameter, shouldn't be instead of `data`, `data()`? For example: `sum_data <- data() %>%` instead of `sum_data <- data %>%`?

Comment: And also insead of `observeEvent(data_mod$trigger,{ rv$data <- data_mod  })` shouldn't be `observeEvent(data_mod()$trigger,{ rv$data <- data_mod  })`? I also don't understand where is `$trigger` come from, so I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: @gss data is a dataframe not a function, so ``data()`` would be incorrect and I got the ``data_mod$trigger`` method from the link attached

Comment: It may not make a difference but your `ui` and `server` assignments are not using the correct "<-" operator. Should `callModule(data_server,"data_table", data=rv$data)` instead be `callModule(data_server,"data_table", data=reactive(rv$data))` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to two things:

1. Using a reactive instead of the data
2. Using the correct namespace

First, though, I just did some house keeping:

- Updated `data_server` and `edit_server` to use `moduleServer` format. This removes the need for `callModule` in the server and is consistent with the other modules
- Drop `observe({  rv$data <- input_data  })` in the server function. It does nothing as `input_data` never changes and is already assigned when the `reactiveValues` object is initialized
- In `edit_server` you look up the column names a lot so I created a variable `dataNames`

With that out of the way, instead of trying to pass just the `data` element of the `reactiveValues` list to your modules, just pass the entire object. It breaks the functional programming nature, but it simplifies the coding. I renamed all the `data` arguments to `rv` to highlight the change. For example:

```
plot_server <- function(id, rv){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session){
      
      output$price_plot <- renderPlot({
        ns <- NS(id)
        rv$data %>%
          ggplot()+
          aes(x=cost,y=updated_price)+
          geom_point()
      })
    })
}
```

Because of this, you also don't need to return a value from `edit_server` as you can modify the object directly as reactives (i.e. R6 objects) are passed by reference. The module's server function becomes this:

```
edit_server <- function(id, rv){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      proxy <- dataTableProxy("data_table")
      
      observeEvent(input$data_table_cell_edit, {
        
        dataNames <- names(rv$data)
        
        print(dataNames)
        info = input$data_table_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        k = info$value
        str(info)
        
        isolate(
          if (j %in% match(c("ratio","cost","updated_price"), dataNames)) {
            print(match(c("ratio","cost", "updated_price"), dataNames))
            rv$data[i, j] <- DT::coerceValue(k, rv$data[i, j])
            print(rv$data)
            
            if (j %in% match("cost", dataNames)) {
              rv$data$updated_price <- rv$data$cost * rv$data$ratio
            }
            if (j %in% match("ratio", dataNames)) {
              rv$data$updated_price <- rv$data$cost * rv$data$ratio
            }
          } else {
            stop("You are not supposed to change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
          }
        )
        replaceData(proxy, rv$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
        
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Probably the biggest thing, however, is to remember the `input` to your module has a namespace based on the `id` argument you pass when calling the module from your server. In the case of `edit_server`, you want it to operate in the same namespace as the data table UI so it can take reactive dependency on the table's `input$data_table_cell_edit`.  Therefore use the same id as the `data_server`:

```
  #data table----------------------
  data_server(id = "data_table", data = rv$data)
  
  #edit table----
  edit_server(id = "data_table", rv = rv)
```

All the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

#summary modules----
summary_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("summary_table"))
}

summary_server <- function(id, rv){
  shiny::moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$summary_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        sum_data <- rv$data %>%
          group_by(Brand) %>%
          summarise_all(list(sum))
        
        DT::datatable(sum_data, editable = TRUE)
      })
    })
}

#data table modules----
data_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("data_table"))
}


data_server <- function(id, data, reset){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      print(isolate(colnames(data)))
      output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data, editable = TRUE)
      })
    }
  )
} 

#edit datatable----
edit_server <- function(id, rv){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      proxy <- dataTableProxy("data_table")
      
      observeEvent(input$data_table_cell_edit, {
        
        dataNames <- names(rv$data)
        
        print(dataNames)
        info = input$data_table_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        k = info$value
        str(info)
        
        isolate(
          if (j %in% match(c("ratio","cost","updated_price"), dataNames)) {
            print(match(c("ratio","cost", "updated_price"), dataNames))
            rv$data[i, j] <- DT::coerceValue(k, rv$data[i, j])
            print(rv$data)
            
            if (j %in% match("cost", dataNames)) {
              rv$data$updated_price <- rv$data$cost * rv$data$ratio
            }
            if (j %in% match("ratio", dataNames)) {
              rv$data$updated_price <- rv$data$cost * rv$data$ratio
            }
          } else {
            stop("You are not supposed to change this column.") # check to stop the user from editing only few columns
          }
        )
        replaceData(proxy, rv$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  # replaces data displayed by the updated table
        
      })
    }
  )
}

#plot modules----
plot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns(id))
}

plot_server <- function(id, rv){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session){
      
      output$price_plot <- renderPlot({
        ns <- NS(id)
        rv$data %>%
          ggplot()+
          aes(x=cost,y=updated_price)+
          geom_point()
      })
    })
}

#dataset-----------------------
input_data <- data.frame(Brand = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3","Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3","Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                         ratio = rep(0.5,9),
                         cost = seq(from=100,to=1000,length.out=9)) %>%
  mutate(updated_price = cost * ratio)

#ui----------------------------------------
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, data_ui(id="data_table")),
    column(6, plot_ui(id="price_plot"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, summary_ui(id="summary_table"))
  ),
)

#server-----------------------------------------
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = input_data, trigger=NULL)
  
  #data table----------------------
  data_server(id = "data_table", data = rv$data)
  
  #edit table----
  edit_server(id = "data_table", rv = rv)
  
  #summary table----
  summary_server(id = "summary_table", rv = rv)
  
  #plot----
  plot_server(id = "price_plot", rv=rv)
}    

#app-----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```